# почему докер контейнер не видит домен в /etc/hosts

Tags: docker, hosts, containers

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть два контейнера `nginx` и `php-fpm` в контейнере `php-fpm` есть файл `/etc/hosts`

```
# php-fpm hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
# ::1             localhost

nginx   server.ser
```

когда я пингую nginx то всё происходит успешно

```
> ping nginx 

64 bytes from nginx (172.24.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from nginx (172.24.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms
```

но как только я пытаюсь пинговать `server.ser` почему-то вместо того что бы взять ip контейнера `nginx` он посылает пакеты на `localhost`,

```
> ping server.ser

64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
```

но почему так происходит если в `/etc/hosts` я указал что по этому домену нужно обраться к `nginx`. В чём может быть проблема?

P.S

если указать в `/etc/hosts` ip контейнера `nginx`то пинг будет успешным,

> 172.0.20.2 server.ser

но разве Docker не может сам подставить ip если в `/etc/hosts` указать просто название контейнера ?

> nginx server.ser

*Спасибо!*

Comment: В файле hosts можно прописывать только IP-адреса, и Docker тут ни при чём

Comment: В разборе содержимого /etc/hosts докер участия не принимает. Непонятно, с чего вы решили, что там можно прописывать названия контейнера.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Тогда единственным вариантом это фиксированный ip у nginx?

Comment: Единственным вариантом решения какой проблемы?

Comment: мне бы хотелось что бы контейнер `php-fpm` мог всегда обращаться по домену `server.ser` который привязан к ip `nginx`, но т.к после рестарта контейнера его ip меняется то единственным решением приходящим мне в голову является статический ip у `nginx`

Comment: В таком случае вам надо сделать server.ser доменом. А так это просто имя контейнера.